# Use XSLT to keep bold and italic html tags in XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I need to import some event XML into InDesign. I'm using an XSLT to reorder and sort this list of events. To bring in the `<eventContent>` I'm using "copy-of" so that it will keep the italic and bold tags. However, InDesign just imports that `<eventContent>` as a large block of text and ignores paragraph returns. When I use "value-of" it keeps the paragraph returns but pulls out the italic and bold tags.

```
<eventlist>
<event>
    <eventTime>12:00AM</eventTime>
    <eventTitle>Movie Night</eventTitle>
    <eventContent>
        <p>Come to the movie night at the new <strong>Middle School</strong></p>
        <p>We will be showing the movie <em>Sing</em></p>
    </eventContent>
</event>
<event>
    <eventTime>05:00AM</eventTime>
    <eventTitle>Dance Party</eventTitle>
    <eventContent>
        <p>Dance at the park!</p>
        <p>Be sure to <strong>bring your own booze</strong>!</p>
    </eventContent>
</event>
</eventlist>
```

Is there a block of code that would allow me to pull in `<eventContent>` and keep the paragraph returns?

Would I add a template to my XSLT to have it cycle through the `<eventContent>` to add a paragraph return code to each `<p>`?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<Root>

<xsl:for-each select="eventlist">
    <eventlist>
    <xsl:for-each select="event">
        <event>
            <eventTime><xsl:value-of select="eventTime"/></eventTime>
            <eventTitle><xsl:value-of select="eventTitle"/></eventTitle>
            <eventContent><xsl:copy-of select="eventContent"/></eventContent>
        </event>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </eventlist>
</xsl:for-each>

</Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "//p" >
    <p><xsl:copy-of select = "." /></p><xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If would be easier to suggest ways to fix your XSLT if you would post your XSLT in your question. An example of the desired output would also be helpful to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Bold and italic tags will not be auto-interpreted by InDesign. You will need to add a character style for both with your XSLT. You can specify the paragraph end in XSLT for InDesign by adding <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>  or  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>after your <p> node.

Answer (score 1):

> InDesign just imports that  as a large block of text and ignores paragraph returns.

Check your InDesign XML Import Options. If you checked "Do Not Import Contents Of Whitespace-Only Elements", then any single "white space" outside tags, leading or tailing inside tags will be removed and you get this blob of text.
Solution is either to uncheck it (but then indents will mount as regular texts) or to implement carriage returns encoded characters such as Nicolai offered.

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about adding the carriage returns to the XML file using XSLT? Is there a way I can have my XSLT cycle through the contents of the <eventContent> and add <xsl:text:>&#10;</xsl:text> to the end of each <p> it finds? I've added an example XSLT to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an explicit carriage return after each `p` element, then instead of the `xsl:copy-of select="eventContent">` - which will perform a deep-copy, you want to transform the content. Change your `xsl:copy-of` to `xsl:apply-templates select="eventContent/*"`, so that each of the `p` elements will match the template that you have defined to match `p` (by the way, the match pattern `p` is sufficient, it does not need to be `//p`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <Root>  
            <xsl:for-each select="eventlist">
                <eventlist>
                    <xsl:for-each select="event">
                        <event>
                            <eventTime><xsl:value-of select="eventTime"/></eventTime>
                            <eventTitle><xsl:value-of select="eventTitle"/></eventTitle>
                            <eventContent><xsl:apply-templates select="eventContent/*"/></eventContent>
                        </event>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </eventlist>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since most of the other content is preserved, instead of reproducing most of it in the template for the root node, you could use a modified [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) and avoid repeating a lot of the XML structure in your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <Root> 
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```